# can't install a python package & use it in a GitHub Action

Tags: python, pip, github-actions

I have a [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/dtenenba/actions-test) with a simple GitHub Actions workflow:

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Run a one-line script
      run: echo Hello, world!
    - name: Run a multi-line script
      run: |
        echo Add other actions to build,
        echo test, and deploy your project.
        pip install twine
        twine --help
```

When I run it, it installs twine, but [fails](https://github.com/dtenenba/actions-test/commit/e554f922b8125cbc662cc9b927658dd51ffe4a7f/checks?check_suite_id=345028062) to run it, saying the command is not found:

```
...
Successfully installed Pygments-2.5.2 bleach-3.1.0 certifi-2019.11.28 chardet-3.0.4 docutils-0.15.2 idna-2.8 pkginfo-1.5.0.1 readme-renderer-24.0 requests-2.22.0 requests-toolbelt-0.9.1 setuptools-42.0.2 six-1.13.0 tqdm-4.40.0 twine-1.15.0 urllib3-1.25.7 webencodings-0.5.1
/home/runner/work/_temp/1643cb1d-8b12-4aa8-8e1d-bd5bba60fd5b.sh: line 4: twine: command not found
```

How can I get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

I am already aware of existing GitHub actions that use twine, they don't do what I want. I also know that I can fork an action and modify it, but what I really want to know is, if I can run `echo hello world` why can't I run `pip install some-pkg; some-pkg ...` ?

It does not seem to be a path problem. I've tried using `python -m twine` in place of `twine`. I tried running a `find` command to find all files on the machine that have `twine` in their name (it didn't find any).

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this will fix the problem, but it's highly recommended anyway. Use the official [`actions/setup-python`](https://github.com/actions/setup-python) action to prepare the environment.

```
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v1
    - name: Run a one-line script
      run: echo Hello, world!
    - name: Run a multi-line script
      run: |
        echo Add other actions to build,
        echo test, and deploy your project.
        pip install twine
        twine --help
```

Comment: I think we should encourage use of the official `setup-python` action because it sets up the environment correctly for different versions of Python, and in a multi-platform way.

Answer (score 1):

Got this to work:

```
pip install --user twine
python -m twine --help
```

Or instead of using `python -m`, specifying the path:

```
~/.local/bin/twine --help
```