# GitHub Action - cannot import pandas_market_calendars after install the pacakge

Tags: python, github, github-actions

I have the problem that after I installed tha package "pandas-market-calendars" when I have my py to import this package, it shows that did find the module.

Here are my ymal codes:

```
name: Daily Python Script

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '15 20 * * *'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  run-script:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'
      
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install pandas
          pip install numpy
          pip install yfinance
          pip install pandas_market_calendars
          pip install datetime
          pip install pytz
      
      
      - name: Run script
        run: |
          python update_raw_data.py && python prepro.py
      
      - name: Commit changes ... removed by me
```

I have run this GitHub script for a month and there is no problem with it. But today it have this error today.

Error message is followed.

```
Run python update_raw_data.py && python prepro.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/stock_prediction/stock_prediction/update_raw_data.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_market_calendars'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please share your yml and your error as text instead of pic. Btw, it seems it doesn't reuse the installed packages from the previous jobs. you may need to cache it. it might: help:https://stackoverflow.com/a/59207205/9391162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed. The reason is becuase pandas_market_calendars does not work properly in v4.2, I downgraded to v4.1.4 and it works fine for now.

Need to wait the new version update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the authors made a packaging error when publishing version 4.2 of the package. This was subsequently [fixed](https://github.com/rsheftel/pandas_market_calendars/commit/e2d45f96c02408d0271adf59941afd9a565f4e91) and released in 4.2.1 which was released 3 hours ago at the time of writing this answer.